# Quick questions about a document example for Components and Data Structures

Tags: differential-equations, documentation, data-structures

`NDSolve` can be broken into several basic steps for advanced usage according to [Components and Data Structures](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#1805463009). In the documentation, a simple example is given as follows.

1. Creating an `` NDSolve`StateData `` object, which includes the info needed to solve the equation:

   ```
    state = First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{x''[t] + (1 + 4 UnitStep[Sin[t]]) x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, t, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"]]

    (* NDSolve`StateData[<0.>] *)
   ```
2. Integrating the equation up to `t = 10 Pi` with the time interval specified by a list of intermediate times

   ```
    NDSolve`Iterate[state, Pi Range[10]]
   ```
3. Generating the current solution and associated derivatives in the forward directon

   ```
    sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state, "Forward"]

    (* {x[31.4159] -> 0.843755, Derivative[1][x][31.4159] -> -1.20016, (x'')[31.4159] -> -0.843755, (x'')[31.4159] -> (x'')[31.4159] -> -1} *)
   ```

I have two questions with regard to the step 2 and 3, respectively.

(1) The document states that **`` NDSolve`Iterate `` allows you to specify intermediate times at which to stop. This can be useful to avoid discontinuities.** It sounds great but I don't understand what does it mean by **at the intermediate times to stop**. Does it mean that by specifying intermediate times we can use `` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions `` to save all the intermediate solutions otherwise we only have a solution for the final time? Can anyone give an example to demonstrate how to avoid discontinuities in solving a differential equation with `` NDSolve`Iterate[state, list_of_times] ``?

(2) I can understand that `` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions `` gives the solution and associated derivatives in the step 3, however, I do not understand what is the last element in its output list, i.e., `(x'')[31.4159] -> (x'')[31.4159] -> -1`?

Comment: I get a different last element, which is the discrete variable used to code the discontinuities arising from `UnitStep`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fo1ux.png -- What version are you using?

Comment: Possibly by "intermediate times to stop," they mean this: ``Table[
 NDSolve`Iterate[state, t0];
 NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state, "Forward"]
 , {t0, Pi Range[10]}]``

Comment: @MichaelE2 Reply to 1st comment: I am using v9 and got the same thing as in the documentation. Did you think that the last element will be problem-dependent? Reply to 2nd comment: Just as I guessed, it allows us to obtain the intermediate solution. Can we save them with `Table[    NDSolve`Iterate[state, t0]; NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state, "Forward"]    ; sol >> ToString[t0].m",  {t0, Pi Range[10]}]`?

Comment: Event handling was changed in version 10.  They added `WhenEvent` on the user-facing side and I expect they changed the internal handling as well (for instance, what we get for `sol`).  What I know about `NDSolve` and discontinuity/event handling I learned post V10.   I have no way of finding out what's different in V9.  What you got, `(x'')[31.4159] -> (x'')[31.4159] -> -1`, can probably be interpreted as `(x'')[31.4159] -> eventsignature` that indicates at `(x'')[31.4159]` the direction the event (which is an equation) is being crossed (decreasing/increasing). That's just a guess, though.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for the explanation.